# ASP.NET Control assign to property null

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls, controls

I have piece of code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _SearchResult.GridViewChanged += _SearchResult_GridViewChanged;
    }

    public Control GvControls { get; set; }

    protected void _SearchResult_GridViewChanged(object sender, Orders.GridViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.GvControls = e.GControl;            
    }

    protected void export_ServerClick()
    {
        new ExportGridView(this.GvControls,"report");
    }
```

One control generate a event with event arg and push a control by arg, then other (this) control do some push-ups with this arg

and when am i try to do push `export_ServerClick()` property `GvControls` equals null but before whould be not null. Why is it happening.

ThankX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables (and even controls) are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle. That's the reason why you have to recreate all dynamically created controls on postback. For the same reason you have to re-initialize a variable with the desired value.

So i assume that the `GridViewChanged`-event is triggered first. Then the user clicks another button that triggers the `export_ServerClick`-event handler. At this point the field `GvControls` has gain it's default value which is `null`.

You have to persist this value somewhere, for example in the `Session`.

[Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

However, i think that you should not need to persist the contol itself. Perhaps it is sufficient to store the ID of the control. Maybe it's even better to load it again from the datasource before you export it for two reasons:

1. the shown data could already be outdated because other users have changed it
2. you you don't need to fiddle around with strings in the control but you have the original values

Comment: but would be possible         `public Control Table
        {
            get { return (Control)Session["gv"]; }
            set { Session["gv"] = value; }
        }`

Comment: Yes, but if you really want to store data in the session i would prefer the real source like a DataTable.

Comment: But my gridview have a special formatting - and really need to delegate this format to excel

Comment: @aleks: but why do you need to persist the grid itself, why is it not sufficient to store only the id,name,type or whatever? The grid is still available on the next postback.